# Showing Or Hiding AdMob Banners - Purchased vs Not-Purchased IAP Banner Non-Consumable

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code that displays a standard AdMob banner depending on whether the user has purchased an ad-free (banner-free) non-consumable In-App Purchase or not (i.e. If purchased, no banners)

UITableViewController - static cells (1 section, X no of rows):

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class WorkoutForehead1Exercise1TVC: UITableViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var product_id: NSString?;

    var banner : GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    product_id = "someFunkyProductName.FullAccess";

    //Check if product is purchased
    if (defaults.boolForKey("purchased"))

    { print("User has purchased ad-free experience") }

    else

    { print("User has not purchased - load banner");

        loadBanner() 
    }

}

func loadBanner(){
    banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/xxxxxx"
    banner.rootViewController = self
    let req : GADRequest = GADRequest()

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["dcf33ab873fb56fdf5ff94bd7a5f3fde", "cd6c1283ff903813bc128342d61521bf"]

    banner.loadRequest(req)
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - banner.frame.size.height, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(banner)
}
```

I have also added a modification to relative TableView cell heights depending on whether the banner (dimensions 320x50) is shown or otherwise. Essentially, I want Row 0 to return 4 pixel height and Row 2 to return 70 pixel height, and Row 1 ("filmstrip") to be variable and fill the rest of the visible screen.

```
// Shrink or increase flimstrip height depending on show banner = true/false:
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if (!defaults.boolForKey("purchased")) {

        print("show banner, reduce filmstrip");
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: height = 4
        case 2: height = 70
        default: height = tableView.frame.size.height - 219
        }
        return height }

        else {

        print("hide banner, increase filmstrip");
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: height = 4
        case 2: height = 70
        default: height = tableView.frame.size.height - 169
        }
        return height
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to run perfectly well in a physical device simulator, but I have the following questions:

1. Can my code be 'neater' or more efficient?
2. Do I need to handle GADBannerViewDelegate protocol's optional -  `adViewDidReceiveAd` and `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` methods? As per Apple app-approval requirements?